# Как правильно удалить Git tracking (контроль версий)?

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Если нужно удалить Git tracking (версионирование), правильно ли просто удалить папку `.git/` ?

Comment: Да. Возможно, ещё удалить `.gitignore` в корне проекта.

Comment: @kff Пишите ответ - приму.

Comment: там ещё может быть файл .gitmodules.

Comment: Полный контекст приведите пожалуйста. Может быть, речь о tracking branch?

Comment: @KoVadim, и `.gitattributes`

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Нет, не о tracking branc. Я имея ввиду полностью удалить отслеживание (как это правильно написать?)

Comment: @Igor "прекратить отслеживание", "удалить версионирование", любые комбинации ))

Comment: и ещё можно пройтись по папкам и удалить файлы .gitkeep - принято, что если нужно сохранить в версионном контроле пустую папку, то в неё добавляют пустой файл .gitkeep

Comment: @AK вроде упомянул их; стоит явно написать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin думаю сейчас достаточно, кто не знает -- по моему комментарию сможет дальше более тщательно разобратся.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4754152

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В этом ответе:

1. Какие файлы и директории относятся к Git
2. Как удалить версионирование Git

   1. Unix, Windows + git bash
   2. Windows, cmd.exe
   3. Windows, проводник
3. Как получить новую копию проекта без версионирования

### 1. Какие файлы и директории относятся к Git

Git хранит историю и настройки в *папках* `.git` и файлах `.git...`. Обязательно существует только папка `.git`, находящаяся в корне вашего проекта. Если в нём есть субмодули, то в наличии есть также файл `.gitmodules` в корне и *файлы* `.git` где-то во вложенных папках.

```
project/
- .git/
- .gitmodules
- .gitignore
- .gitattributes
- пустая-папка/
  - .gitkeep
- ещё-папка/и-ещё/внутри/
  - .git
  - .gitignore
  - тут-файлы-и-папки-субмодуля
```

### 2. Как удалить версионирование Git

#### Unix-совместимые системы, Windows c git bash или cygwin:

Убедитесь, что вы находитесь в корне проекта!

```
cd path/to/project
find . -name ".git*" | xargs rm -ri
```

С ключом `-i` эта команда будет работать в интерактивном режиме и запросит подтверждение на удаление каждого файла. [Спасибо KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541242/%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-git-tracking-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF/541258?noredirect=1#comment685165_541258) за улучшенный вариант первоначальной команды.

#### Windows, cmd.exe

(взято c [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36945328/2790048) )

```
cd path\to\project
del /F /S /Q /A .git
rmdir .git
```

#### Windows, через проводник

1. Включите отображение скрытых файлов и папок
2. Откройте папку своего проекта, найдите поле поиска:

   [image: поле поиска]
3. Введите там `filename:.git`, дождитесь окончания поиска:

   [image: результат поиска]

   Заметьте, что другие виды поиска работают хуже: `name:.git` включает файлы наподобие `source.git.cs`, `ext:.git` не включает каталог `.git`, просто `.git` включает медленный и ненужный поиск по содержимому файлов
4. Теперь вы можете выбрать файлы, относящиеся к git, и удалить (скорее всего, это будут *все* найденные файлы). Перепроверить, однако, не помешает никогда.

### 3. Как получить новую копию проекта без версионирования

Возможно, вам нужно просто получить копию проекта, в которой нет версионирования. Для этого отлично подходит git-archive:

```
git archive master --format zip --output path/to/archive.zip
```

Полученный archive.zip можно передать и где-то распаковать, получив новый проект без версионирования.

Субмодули таким образом не упакуются.

Comment: можно конечно, но мне не понятно, почему поиск не написать так `find . -name ".git* | xargs rm -rfi`. Данная команда мало того, что будет работать быстрее, так ещё и переспросит на каждое удаление.

Comment: @KoVadim, NickVolynkin опции `-i` и `-f` программы *rm* логически как бы взаимоисключающи (см. [третий абзац](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/rm-invocation.html)). в код не заглядывал, поэтому допускаю, что при наличии/отсутствии опции `-f` (и присутствии опции `-i`) набор выполняемых на каждой итерации инструкций может чуть отличаться, но с точки зрения пользователя поведение самой программы — идентично. т.е. опция `-f` в данном случае излишня.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin принято, поправил.

Answer (score 4):

*Git* хранит всю историю и настройки отслеживания проекта в папке с именем `.git`, находящейся в корне проекта. Поэтому для прекращения отслеживания достаточно удалить эту папку.

Но, возможно, в корне проекта присутствуют и другие файлы, относящиеся к *Git*. Например, это может быть файл `.gitignore`, в котором хранятся имена неотслеживаемых объектов.

Comment: тогда нужно видимо сказать так - скорее всего нужно удалить все файлы и папки по маске `.git*`.

Answer (score -1):

Если в файловом менеджере не видна папка /.git, то в консоль можно установить Midnight Commander. И находясь в папке, куда инициализировался проект, выполнить команду mc, в консоли откроется файловый менеджер, в котором будет доступна папка /.git. Ctrl+F8 удалит папку. И все.

Просто у меня не сработала интерактивность в команде из решения (find . -name ".git*" | xargs rm -ri). Хотя я работаю в юникс-подобной операционке (Finder зло).