# Как отключить систему управления версиями Git?

Tags: visual-studio, git, github

Подскажите, как отключить систему управления версиями Git, при использовании расширения GitHub Extension for Visual Studio, слишком рано ее включил...

Используется Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отличие вопроса состоит в том, что для новичка в Visual Studio функция "Добавить решение в систему управления расширениями..." включает систему управления версиями. И тем же способом хочется ее отключить, но этого в меню нет. По сочетаниям слов (система управления версиями Git) я и стал искать ответ.

Слова "версионирование", "git tracking", "git init", не придут в голову новичку, и уж тем более не придет в голову удалять какую-то папку. Ищем функцию отключения системы управления версиями, а получаем удаление папки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда не рано включить систему контроля версий.

Comment: @mymedia вопрос-то тут про visual studio, а не про git. Так что ни разу не дубликат.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ответ на этот вопрос такой же как и тут и не зависит от IDE. А ещё есть вот такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428154

Comment: @mymedia тот факт, что ответ не зависит от IDE, и является предметом вопроса. Это далеко не очевидный факт.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _" Вопросы могут считаться дубликатами, если на них получены (могут быть получены) одинаковые ответы"._  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5219

Comment: @mymedia в данном случае ответы не одинаковы: ответ на этот вопрос несет скрытый смысл (кроме удаления папки больше ничего делать не надо)

Comment: @PavelMayorov вообще то Visual Studio при включении версионирования не только папку .git создаёт. После нажатия той кнопки, что на снимке экрана, впридачу ещё   появляется и .gitignore

Comment: @mymedia вот видите. Эту информацию надо уже в ответ включать. Тогда они не будут одинаковыми.

Comment: @PavelMayorov в смысле? По первой ссылке там предлагают удалять и .git, и .gitignore, и некоторые другие файлы. А тутошний ответ малокачественный.

Comment: @mymedia это проблема ответа, а не вопроса

Comment: @PavelMayorov так какое же будет решение?

Comment: @mymedia улучши ответ или создай новый

Comment: @Alex78191, но меня устраивают ответы, которые можно найти по приведённым выше ссылкам. Мне пока нечего добавить к ним.

Comment: @mymedia Я говорю ответ добавить на вопрос

Comment: @Alex78191, там уже есть ответы на этот вопрос.

Comment: @mymedia Я про ответ на этом сайте

Comment: В том вопросе слово "версионирование" мне бы никогда не выпало в похожих вопросах. И сам вопрос настолько замудренный, что не ясна его суть. Даже в гугле не нашел бы его.

Comment: @Alex78191 так ответ(ы) и есть на этом сайте, просто в другом вопросе. [Лучше не отвечать на вопрос-дубликат, а добавить ответ в основной вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5219/181472)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вы комментарии удалили и непонятно где был ответ

Comment: @Alex78191 которые под вашим ответом были — те удалил за неконструктивностью спора о том, насколько «О боже» пользоваться видеоинструкцией. А к вопросу комментарий со ссылкой удалился автоматически — теперь эта ссылка есть в самом вопросе.

Comment: @Vitokhv так бывает, у одной проблемы может быть много различных описаний и формулировок. Настолько много, что все не впихнуть в заголовок вопроса. Теоретически, можно тексты «наСЕОшивать», но это будет смотреться уродливо и дико. Так что это нормально, что вы не нашли. Благодаря вашему вопросу теперь больше людей будут находить ответы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Папку .git удали, которая находится в корне решения

Comment: Ответ неполный: студия создает не только папку `.git`. [Как удалить все относящиеся к git файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541258/181472).

Comment: Nick Volynkin ты мне объясни для начала, каким образом я бы нашел данный ответ по словам - "Как удалить все относящиеся к git файлы.". Мне, что надо было искать по словам "относящиеся к git файлы"? У меня на тот момент в Visual Studio была лишь функция "Добавить решение в систему управления расширениями...". По этим сочетаниям слов я и стал искать ответ! И для меня как новичку казалось, что есть подобная функция в меню Visual Studio или в расширении GitHub Extension, мой вопрос правильный, со смыслом. Тебе просто не жаль тех, кто не найдет ответа по сочетанию вопроса который ты предоставил.

Comment: @Vitokhv так вопрос остался, тебе же не говорят, что его задавать не надо было.